# Dynamic SEO Friendly URLs in Yii

Tags: content-management-system, yii, seo

I want to use custom dynamic seo friendly urls in yii.

I read all kind of articles and they all say the same thing.

This is what i managed to find so far, and it does not suit my needs:

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

or

```
array(
     '<_c:(post|comment)>/<id:\d+>/<_a:(create|update|delete)>'=>'<_c>/<_a>',
     '<_c:(post|comment)>/<id:\d+>'=>'<_c>/view',
     '<_c:(post|comment)>s/*'=>'<_c>/list',
)
```

I dont need urls like: domain.com/a/b/c/d

I need: domain.com/here-goes-the-article-title-ACTION-ID

I need a expression that can identify the article title.

This is how one of my urls looks like: http://www.linkbook.ro/concurs-castiga-o-invitatie-de-trei-zile-de-festival-la-bestfest-2012-detailsU-2-882.html

where concurs-castiga-o-invitatie-de-trei-zile-de-festival-la-bestfest-2012 is the article title

detailsU is the action

2 is the database id

882 is the article id

Comment: You're probably going to end up having to write your own UrlRule class and put it first in the rules array. Given that you do not use any controller/action in the URL it's either that or have Yii route everything through the default controller/action and parse it there. I wrote my own url router but I choose to require a controller in the url, which makes it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me formulate my comment as an answer. You still have to implement some stuff yourself, but this should get you started:

```
class MyRule extends CBaseUrlRule
{
  public function parseUrl($oManager, $oRequest, $sPathInfo, $sRawPathInfo)
  {
    // Extract database Id and article Id from $sPathInfo and perhaps put it in $_REQUEST
    if ("url isn't SEO thingy")
      return FALSE:        
    return 'articles/index';
  }

  public function createUrl($oManager, $sRoute, $aParameters, $sAmpersand)
  {
     if ("i have an SEO item to show")
       return "/however you want to assemble your URL"; 
     return FALSE; 
  }
}
```

The above example assumes that you route everything through the articles controller (action index).

Adding to the config is a matter of adding the following to your rules:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            array('class' => 'MyRule'),
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```